# Getting and Setting CSS() not working...Toggle Height

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to basically toggle a height from 50px to 200px. i wrote this code to check and see if the height is 50px, if it is set it to 200, it its any other value set it to 50. Basically a toggle functon

```
$('.this-row').click(function(){
console.log("click "+$('.this-row').css('height'));
if($('.this-row').css('height','50')){
    $('.this-row').css('height','200')
    }
else 
    $('.this-row').css('height','50')

 });
```

In the css i have initially .this-row{height:50px}. Right now it'll check the height and set to 200, but the opposite logic isnt working on the next clicks

Comment: You're setting the height in an if condition. You should probably compare it to something.

Comment: This would be easier if you just add/remove/toggle a css class

Comment: thanks guys! i guess i was over complicating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your condition you are using the setter, so you are always making the height 50px before testing it. Try this:

```
if ($('.this-row').css('height') == '50') {
    $('.this-row').css('height','200')
}
else 
    $('.this-row').css('height','50') 
});
```

You could shorten this by using a ternary:

```
$row = $('.this-row');
$row.css('height', $row.css('height') == '50' ? '200' : '50');
```

Or even better still, by using a class to separate UI from markup entirely:

```
$('.this-row').toggleClass('tall');
```

```css
.tall {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: `$row.css('height')` will return something like `'50px'`. The condition will not work.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon that's true. I'll leave that for the OP to investigate and solve.

Answer (score 0):

jQuerys [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method is perfect for this.

CSS:

```
.this-row { height: 50px; }
.height2 { height: 200px; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.this-row').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('height2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to evaluate the height in the conditional, not set it, changing your code to something like the following:

```
$('.this-row').click(function(){
  var height = $('.this-row').css('height');
  console.log("click "+height);
  if(height == '50') {
    $('.this-row').css('height','200')
  }
  else {
    $('.this-row').css('height','50')
  }
});
```

Will test the height value of the style associated with the element defined by the class `.this-row`; since you're working with the height value a few times, you can read it into a local variable to reduce duplicate processing. This conditional is testing to see if the height is 50px.